# Calculate Determinant Using Diagonal Product Method

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have a 4x4 matrix:

```
1 3 5 9
1 3 1 7
4 3 9 7
5 2 0 9
```

By my understanding, the determinant should be -173. Here's my work:

```
(243+105+280+0) - (135+126+0+540) = -173
```

I tried this matrix on two different online calculators and they both came up with -376.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Even if you just show your calculations I should be able to figure out where my understanding is wrong. Thanks

Update: Anyone coming here looking to learn something from this post, there is only one thing of use here: the "diagonal product" method does not work for matrices 4x4 and up.

Comment: What is the "diagonal product method"? Explain.

Comment: The issue is the shortcut doesn't have a formal name, as far as I know, and it's not even a standard trick as far as I know. (I've seen some use it, but I think it's been avoided in a lot of classes I've had that touch on determinants.) Probably for good reason, since, as stated in my answer, it simply doesn't generalize to higher matrices. Sucks but that's life. [cont]

Comment: You should explain what YOU think the diagonal product method is, since you're not getting the right result.

Comment: Digression aside, in general, if you want help on this site, it would behoove you to actually include details like that (even if obvious ***to you***), for the sake of helping people better help you, and to make your result more easily parsed and searched. Especially as opposed to an at-best-unhelpful response that amounts to "Google it yourself." [cont.]

Comment: For those curious, the method in question is this. Consider the determinant

$$\left| \begin{matrix}
a_x & a_y & a_z \\
b_x & b_y & b_z \\
c_x & c_y & c_z \end{matrix} \right|$$

To calculate this with the "trick", start at the top row. From a fixed entry, move down one and right one, "warping" to the opposite side of the matrix if you "go through" the right side -- Pac-Man style. Multiply the starting entry with the two entries met on the way. (Starting from $a_z$, you would then get $a_z b_x c_y$.) [cont]

Comment: Do this for all three top entries, and add them up. (For argument's sake, call the result $A$.) Then do all of this again, but instead go down and left this time. (Hence you will get, say, $a_y b_x c_z$.) Call the result $B$. Then the determinant is $A-B$. The result is identical to the usual method (even in its calculation, really: you're just not explicitly doing the work of the Laplace expansion).

Comment: An extra addendum for the curious: apparently, as I just learned, the shortcut has a name -- [the rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus). Dunno where that name comes from though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is you're generalizing the shortcut method some (like myself) like to use for $3 \times 3$ matrices.

As far as I know no such shortcut exists for a $4 \times 4$ or higher order matrix, beyond (technically) the Laplace expansion, which is how the determinant is usually taught. And no, this method you're using does not work for such matrices.

As a more basic example consider

$$\newcommand{\m}[1]{\left| \begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix} \right|}
\m{ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
13 & 14 & 15 & 16}$$

We have this matrix we use as a reference for signs:

$$\m{+ & - & + & -\\
- & + & - & + \\
+ & - & + & - \\
- & + & - & +}$$

(Essentially, you start row $1$ as an alternating series of pluses and minuses, and on the next row use the opposite signs from the first row, on the third use those opposite the second, and so on.)

Choose a row or column from your matrix, whatever one is most "convenient." (A convenient row or column would have a lot of zeroes, typically.) Then, for each entry in that row or column, delete that entry's entire row or column, and find the determinant of what remains, times the outside factor, and times $+1/-1$ as depending on the sign matrix above. Then add all of the results up.

Expanding along the first row in our example, we get

$$\begin{align*}
\m{ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
13 & 14 & 15 & 16} &= 1 \cdot \m{ 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 14 & 15 & 16}
- 2 \cdot \m{ 5 & 7 & 8 \\ 9 & 11 & 12 \\ 13 & 15 & 16}\\
&\;\;\; + 3 \cdot \m{ 5 & 6 & 8 \\ 9 & 10 & 12 \\ 13 & 14 & 16}
- 4 \cdot \m{5 & 6 & 7 \\ 9 & 10 & 11 \\ 13 & 14 & 15}
\end{align*}
$$

You can also use this on $3 \times 3$ matrices (with results identical to the shortcut) and even on $2 \times 2$ matrices if you want (if you take the determinant of $1 \times 1$ matrix to be just the lone entry itself).

Comment: Is your answer being downvoted because you answered a question that didn't put in enough effort in their question? I have seen this phenomena a lot on this website.

Comment: Maybe. I don't pretend to know, or care really. I feel like OP put in sufficient effort, and I at least understand their method, but their unhelpfulness (as seen in the comments of the question itself) is certainly not helping matters. The question as it stands could be improved, obviously.

Comment: You shouldn't answer someone who says things like "I should not have to explain it in my question” or "just google it”. By doing this you encourage people to continue with that rude behavior.

Comment: PrincessEev, from what I've found, this method works for large matrices. The columns are repeated so that all complete diagonals of each original column can be calculated. I've watched youtube videos where the author goes over the mechanics and that's what they've done. Having said that, and given that you see this as questionable trick, is there a name for the method that you prefer for large matrices that I could explore?

Comment: "PrincessEev, from what I've found, this method works for large matrices." Well, evidently, you've found a counterexample to the method for a $4 \times 4$ case in your OP. There are certainly some matrices for which it *technically* would work (triangular ones, for instance), but it doesn't hold in general, as you have seen. As far as what the name of the method I'm using is called, it's simply called the "Laplace expansion", though a lot of times people just won't refer to it by a name (since it's typically the first way people are introduced to determinants).

Comment: Thanks PrincessEev, I could very well have been blinded by the simplicity and am generalizing as you suggested. Thanks for the Laplace expansion, I'll explore it. And thank you very much for being kind and trying to help in a situation where you could have easily concluded I did not deserve help! You were right though, I've been working on this for days, and it seemed to me that it was time to ask for help. I didn't get what I wanted but I got what I needed: redirection to another method.